# SQL select query using Joins with aggregate counts

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a table with the following fields:

```
tickets:  id, createddate, resolutiondate
```

A sample set of data has:

```
jira=# select * from tickets;
   id    | createddate | resolutiondate
---------+-------------+----------------
 ticket1 | 2020-09-21  | 2020-10-01
 ticket2 | 2020-09-22  | 2020-09-23
 ticket3 | 2020-10-01  |
 ticket4 | 2020-10-01  | 2020-10-04
 ticket5 | 2020-10-01  |
 ticket6 | 2020-10-01  | 2020-10-07
(6 rows)

jira=#
```

I would like to create a query which reports:

```
Week:  Issues Created:  Issues Resolved
```

I can do the two separate queries:

```
# select date_trunc('week', createddate) week, count(id) created
    from tickets
    group by week
    order by week desc
    ;
          week          | created
------------------------+---------
 2020-09-28 00:00:00+00 |       4
 2020-09-21 00:00:00+00 |       2
(2 rows)

# select date_trunc('week', resolutiondate) week, count(id) resolved
    from tickets
    where resolutiondate is not NULL
    group by week
    order by week desc
    ;

          week          | resolved
------------------------+----------
 2020-10-05 00:00:00+00 |        1
 2020-09-28 00:00:00+00 |        2
 2020-09-21 00:00:00+00 |        1
(3 rows)
```

However - I can not figure out how (with a join, union, sub-query, ...?) to combine these queries into a combined query with the appropriate aggregations.

I'm doing this is Postgres - any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performing a union before aggregating values may work here eg

```sql
select week, 
       count(id_created) as created,
       count(id_resolved) as resolved
from (
    select date_trunc('week', resolutiondate) week, NULL as id_created, id as id_resolved from tickets UNION ALL
    select date_trunc('week', createddate) week, id as id_created, NULL as id_resolved from tickets
) t
    group by week
    order by week desc
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Does the trick - pretty slick.